# C++ Read file into vectors

Tags: c++, file, vector

I'm having trouble figuring out how to read a file line by line into different data type vectors. Is there a way to do this with inFile >> ? My code is below. Thanks in advance!

```
void fileOpen()
{
    fstream inFile;
    inFile.open(userFile);

    // Check if file open successful -- if so, process

    if (!inFile.is_open()) {cout << "File could not be opened.";}
    else
    {
        cout << "File is open.\n";

        string firstLine;
        string line;

        vector<char> printMethod;
        vector<string> shirtColor;
        vector<string> orderID;
        vector<string> region;
        vector<int> charCount;
        vector<int> numMedium;
        vector<int> numLarge;
        vector<int> numXL;

        getline(inFile, firstLine); // get column headings out of the way
        cout << firstLine << endl << endl;

        while(inFile.good()) // while we are not at the end of the file, process
        {
            while(getline(inFile, line)) // get each line of the file separately
            {
               for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++)
               {
                  inFile >> date >> printMethod.at(i);
                  cout << date << printMethod.at(i) << endl;
               }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `push_back` to add an item to a `vector`. I don't think that you can get `at` member function with an index that is out-of-range.

Comment: the date variable is nowhere defined

Answer (score 0):

Before you use `vector.at(i)` in your case you should be sure that your vector is long enough cause [`at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) will generate out of range exception. As I can see from your code your vector `printMethod` contains no more than 50 elements so you can resize vector `printMethod` before use e.g.

```
vector<char> printMethod(50);
```

or

```
vector<char> printMethod;
printMethod.resize(50);
```

If you're planning to use a variable number of elements more than 50 you should use push_back method like @Phil1970 recommended e.g.

```
char other_data;
inFile >> date >> other_data;
printMethod.push_back(other_data);
```